# AsyncTask won't let me use my own class

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I have an AsyncTask to load entries in a ListView by creating everytime a new instance of a class, where the varaibles will be saved and let them load from an own Adapter which is extended as a BaseAdapter.

The class looks like this:

```
public class PictureResults
{
    private long id;
    private String pictureURL;

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setPictureURL(String pictureURL)
    {
        this.pictureURL = pictureURL;
    }

    public String getPictureURL()
    {
        return pictureURL;
    }
}
```

This is my AsyncTask class:

```
private class getPictureDataTask extends AsyncTask<Long, String, Void>
    {
        protected PictureResults doInBackground(Long... param)
        {
                PictureResults pr;

                pr = new PictureResults();
                pr.setId(param[0]);
                pr.setPictureURL("http://www.myurl.com");

                return pr;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... response)
        {
            //do nothing
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(PictureResults ret)
        {
            picResults.add(ret); //picResults is an ArrayList<PictureResults>
            ret.loadPicture(customAdapter);
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

The main problem which appears is that Eclipse let me know the following:

```
The return type is incompatible with AsyncTask<Long,String,Void>.doInBackground(Long[])
```

It is important that especially the `customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` will be executed in `onPostExecute` because in `onProgressUpdate` sometimes my app crashes causing of changing the ListView from a background thread.

Why I can't use PictureResults as a type???

BTW: This is how I execute the AsyncTask:

```
Long hey = (long) 1;
new getPictureDataTask().execute(hey);
```

Comment: when you extend AsyncTask<1,2,3>, 3 refers to doInBackground return object, so you should change that from Void to PictureResults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third type parameter of `AsyncTask` should be `PictureResults` not `Void`

```
class getPictureDataTask extends AsyncTask<Long, String, PictureResults>
```

Because the 3rd Parameter Type of `AsyncTask` is what kind of data result should be returned. If you don't want to return any result from `doInBackground()`, use `Void` and then `return null;`

Answer (score 0):

You should change this to  AsyncTask

Comment: Do you mean the "this" in my class? And how do I change it, that my class will work?

Comment: Sorry I didn't paste this part. I mean the voidwith AsyncTask<Long,String,PictureResults > like this

Answer (score 0):

when you wanted return PictureResults, you should be declare in the AsyncTask.

```
private class getPictureDataTask extends AsyncTask<Long, String, PictureResults>
{
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the 3 parameters in the angle brackets while you implements your AsyncTask.

```
AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

The Params is take by the doInBackground() method which you passing it when you start the task with excute();
The Result should be return by the doInBackground() method and will be taken by the method onPostExecute(Result ret).
Each should be of the type you hava defined when you implements you custom task class.
More information is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

you should change your AsyncTask to  AsyncTask